# How to bind click events to a different class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

So I have two click events for "button-open" and "button-close". I have one button that switches from "button-open" to "button-close" on click. So when i click it again, it should fire the event for "button-close" but instead it fires the event for "button-open" again.
Demo : [jsFidde](http://jsfiddle.net/UhVuq/)

Here's my code:

```
<a href="#" class="button-open">Button</a>​

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".button-open").click(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("button-open").addClass("button-close");
      alert("Open Was Clicked");
   });

   $(".button-close").click(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("button-close").addClass("button-open");
      alert("Close Was Clicked");
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `click()`, since you need to bind to an element that doesn't yet exist when you initially bind it.

```
$(document).on('click', '.button-open', function() {
    $(this).removeClass("button-open").addClass("button-close");
    alert("Open Was Clicked");
});


$(document).on('click', '.button-close', function() {
    $(this).removeClass("button-close").addClass("button-open");
    alert("Close Was Clicked");
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UhVuq/3/)**.